# How fbsr Cookie is set in website by facebook

Tags: facebook, cookies

I have came across a website , I logged in using facebook connect.After logged in when i typed `document.cookie` I came across something like below

```
fbsr_1191783812334566=cencoredsomecodehere-somecodehere_Wj9VyFLGW2fKQ.eyJhbGdvcml0aG0iOiJITUFDLVNIQTI1NiIsImNvZGUiOiJBUUMwek5zeFlDU3Nzd1BtcE9zLTVOaWdSU1lYMEJwRlJ3NDdoLTlWSlZ1ZTBJ
```

How this fbsr cookie is set ? Is it done via server or client.Some one care to explain me ? I dont find it facebook documentation.

Comment: Yes the server set it. Why?

Comment: You wont find it anywhere in the FB documentation because I think FB doesn't have anything to do with this. The application (web server) that you visited might have set it for its own use.